# Regex Pattern that gets string from two line

Tags: c#, regex

I have created and tested this Regexpattern `<\w\w:Value> SYMBOL: (P.*)=(.*)\/\/(.*)`

```
 Regex regexPattern = new Regex(@"<\w\w:Value> SYMBOL: (P.*)=(.*)\/\/(.*)");
 var attributeChecker = regexPattern.Match(line);
 var attributeLongDescription = attributeChecker.Groups[3].ToString().Trim();
```

Here is the model:

```
<AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWFNA     = 0;        // Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht
                                          // auswerten
<AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWLE      = 0;        // Länge des Durchrutschweges
```

The results that I am getting, from group three are:

```
Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht
Länge des Durchrutschweges
```

How can I get these results from Group three:

```
Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht auswerten
Länge des Durchrutschweges
```

Comment: You cannot do that, you need to match all the lines below your pattern match that are continuation of the comment, and then post-process the result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please give me an example, how should I do that ?

Comment: I was working on the code but you have got an answer already.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you have a better answer you can post yours and I will remove mine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I want your idea too. Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you very much , I am waiting and Wiktors  answer =)

Comment: It will be very similar...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  but with that I am getting `// Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht                                           // auswerten` not `Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht auswerten`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please check whether the recent edit has invalidated the question.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Now, the question is 1) different, 2) unclear as there is no input text, no sample to test the pattern against. kn1ghtx, please keep the question as it was, and if there is just a slight issue with the current solution, please drop a comment below the answer(s) and if it is a bigger thing, please consider asking a new question. Rolling back to the latest normal question for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot capture disjoint parts of a string into a single capturing group. You need to match all the lines below your pattern match that are continuation of the comment, and then post-process the result.

You can use the following approach (see the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/vxKJys)):

```cs
var text = @"<AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWFNA     = 0;        // Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht
                                          // auswerten
<AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWLE      = 0;        // Länge des Durchrutschweges";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"<\w{2}:Value> SYMBOL: (P.*)=(.*)//(.*(?:\n[\s-[\r\n]]*//.*)*)");
foreach (Match m in matches) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- A new match ---");
    Console.WriteLine($"Group 1: {m.Groups[1].Value}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Group 2: {m.Groups[2].Value}");
    Console.WriteLine("Group 3: {0}",
        string.Join(" ", 
            m.Groups[3].Value.Split(new[] {"//"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Trim())
        )
    );
}
```

Output:

```cs
--- A new match ---
Group 1: PDWFNA     
Group 2:  0;        
Group 3: Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht auswerten
--- A new match ---
Group 1: PDWLE      
Group 2:  0;        
Group 3: Länge des Durchrutschweges
```

See also the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5cw%7b2%7d%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+%28P.*%29%3d%28.*%29%2f%2f%28.*%28%3f%3a%5cn%5b%5cs-%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%5d*%2f%2f.*%29*%29&i=%3cAC%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+PDWFNA+++++%3d+0%3b++++++++%2f%2f+Projektierung+D-Weg+Freimeldung+nicht%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2f%2f+auswerten%0d%0a%3cAC%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+PDWLE++++++%3d+0%3b++++++++%2f%2f+L%c3%a4nge+des+Durchrutschweges).

The `(.*(?:\n[\s-[\r\n]]*//.*)*)` part captures into Group 3 the rest of the current line with `.*`, then any zero or more lines that can start with zero or more whitespaces other than CR and LF, then have `//` and then anything till the end of the line.

The `string.Join(" ", m.Groups[3].Value.Split(new[] {"//"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim()))` is one way of post-processing Group 3 value. Here, it is split with `//` substring and then all the resulting items get stripped from leading/trailing whitespace and then they are joined into a single string with a space.

You may also use `Regex.Replace(m.Groups[3].Value, @"\s*//\s*", " ")` instead to make it shorter.

Comment: Just FYI: if the comment lines can contain blank lines in between replace `[\s-[\r\n]]` with just `\s`.

Comment: Nice, is `[\s-[\r\n]]` the same as `[\p{Zs}\t]`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird `[\s-[\r\n]]` is more equal to `[^\S\r\n]`. `[\p{Zs}\t]` is more specific.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback as well. Let me put my vote here++

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much for that amazing answer. I hope you could help me in this little part too. There are some lines like this: `// ********** NEUE DATENZEILE ********************************************************` . The Regexpattern should not get these. Could you please help me ?!

Comment: @kn1ghtx You probably want to exclude the comments that are followed with aterisks, try ``<\w{2}:Value> SYMBOL: (P.*)=(.*)//(?!\s*\*)(.*(?:\n[\s-[\r\n]]*//(?!\s*\*).*)*)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have just another question. Does this pattern work if I give Regex as input "line for line" not all the text ?!

Comment: @kn1ghtx Of course not. `\n`  in the regex pattern needs to find an LF char, and when you read line by line, there is no LF in the input.

Answer (score 1):

After the matching, you can process the match of group 3, removing the leading newline, the spaces and `//`

```
<\w\w:Value> SYMBOL: (P[^=\n]*)=(.*?)//(.*(?:\n[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `<\w\w:Value> SYMBOL:`  Match literally
- `(P[^=\n]*)` Capture group 1, match `P` followed by not `=` or a newline
- `=` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture group 2, match any char except a newline non greedy
- `//` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `.*`  Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\n[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*` Match a newline, optional spaces and // and the rest of the line
  - `)*` Close
- `)` Close group 3

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5cw%5cw%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+%28P%5b%5e%3d%5cn%5d*%29%3d%28.*%3f%29%2f%2f%28.*%28%3f%3a%5cn%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%2f%2f.*%29*%29&i=%3cAC%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+PDWFNA+++++%3d+0%3b++++++++%2f%2f+Projektierung+D-Weg+Freimeldung+nicht%0d%0a++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2f%2f+auswerten%0d%0a%3cAC%3aValue%3e+SYMBOL%3a+PDWLE++++++%3d+0%3b++++++++%2f%2f+L%c3%a4nge+des+Durchrutschweges) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/il7arI)

For example, printing only group 3 after the replacement:

```
string pattern = @"<\w\w:Value> SYMBOL: (P[^=\n]*)=(.*?)//(.*(?:\n[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*)*)";
string input = @"<AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWFNA     = 0;        // Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht
                                            // auswerten
    <AC:Value> SYMBOL: PDWLE      = 0;        // Länge des Durchrutschweges"; 
        
            
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(match.Groups[3].Value, @"\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]+//",""));              
}
```

Output

```
Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht auswerten
Länge des Durchrutschweges
```

Comment: `\r?` is unnecessary, `.` already matches CR symbols. `//` can also start at the line beginning.

Comment: thanks, but with that I am getting `// Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht
                                          // auswerten`
not  `Projektierung D-Weg Freimeldung nicht auswerten`